# java multiplying numbers between a range

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

public static int sum = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(factorial(4,8));
}

public static  long factorial(long min , long max ){

    if(max >= min) {
        sum *= max;
        max -= 1;
        factorial(min ,max);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

}

```
 public class Main {

public static int sum = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(factorial(4,8));
}

public static  long factorial(long min , long max ){

    while(max >= min) {
        sum *= max;
        max -= 1;
        factorial(min ,max);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

}

why does the one with while in it give me an error while the other one with the if statement works, this code is supposed to multiply all of the numbers between the range (min and max) so for example factorial(4,8) = 8*7*6*5*4

Comment: the code with the while is looping **and** calling factorial recursively. (But you don't do anything with the result of factorial in the while version. you can simply delete this line.

Comment: Your while statement is a loop in itself. So it's attempting to run a loop WHILE calling itself again recursively. So the while should work if you remove your `factorial(min, max)` from the bottom of the loop.

Comment: also, when you post code that gives any error, please explain in details what is the error, with error message or expected vs actual output.

Comment: *FYI:* Both are horrendous. Remove field `sum`. The recursive method should not be updating a field. Re-think your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the error you are getting, but if you put your recursive call to factorial() in a while loop you are creating a recursive call for each iteration of your loop.  Each recursive call will have it's own while loop, with it's own set of recursive calls, and you end up with a lots of calls on your stack.

Also, in both versions of your program, you are not doing anything with the return value of your recursive call.  So while you are not getting an error with your first version, it is not going to correctly calculate the factorial.  Try something like this:

```
public static long factorial(long min, long max, long result) {

    if(max >= min) {
        result *= max;
        max -= 1;
        return factorial(min, max, result);
    }
   return result;
}
```

And you would invoke it like so:

```
factorial(4, 8, 1);
```

Comment: originally, I pinpointed that the OP is not using the return value of the recursive functions too, but we are kind of wrong, as each recursive call changes the value of `sum` which is a static property of the object. So, in a sense the results are not ignored. (even though it is clearly not the best way of doing it)

Comment: Ah, yes you're right @KyrSt, I missed that.  Just an usual way to do recursion I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll dry run the code, you will observe where the problem lies.
You are mixing iteration and recursion in the second case.

factorial(2,4):

sum = 4
max = 3

sum = 4*3
max = 2

sum = 4*3*2
max = 1

sum = 4*3*2
max = 3

So, at this step you can see, when the recursive call returns it uses it's local copy of `max` i.e. 3. This leads to extra multiplication.

This is not the case in code 1, where you don't do a while loop.